# For cops and robbers, what if the cops' thread is closed / put on hold?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, cops-and-robbers

If someone posts a [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge and the cops' thread is closed / put on hold, for any reason (e.g: *unclear what you're asking*), what should happen to the robbers' thread? Should it be closed as well or should we just leave it open? If it should be closed, what close-reason should be chosen, the same as the other thread?

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117318/cheapo-enigma-machine-cops) is an example, where the cops' thread is put on hold, but the other isn't.

Comment: I would vote to close the other challenge with an other reason explaining the situation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Close the robbers thread.

If a challenge is closed, then no answers can be posted. [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenges are made of two separate questions. Since we are closing challenges and not questions per se, we should close both threads, since otherwise robbing can continue even though the challenge is closed.